# Auto-dropped Dropdown Menu, what is it called?

Tags: jquery, css, menu

[Amazon's website](http://www.amazon.com/)
Description:

Under 'Shop by Department'-

A dropped-down Dropdown Menu without needing to 'hover' it..
However, when the browser is not full-screen, the menu disappears and you need to hover the menu to show the Dropdown.

What is the official name for it?

Comment: still a dropdown whether it's open by default or not

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terminology rather than a technical question.

Comment: Where should they put this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon dropdown (more specifically Mega-dropdown) has been reverse engineered here https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim and you can read more about it here. http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown

> At every position of the cursor you can picture a triangle between the
> current mouse position and the upper and lower right corners of the
> dropdown menu. If the next mouse position is within that triangle, the
> user is probably moving their cursor into the currently displayed
> submenu. Amazon uses this for a nice effect. As long as the cursor
> stays within that blue triangle the current submenu will stay open. It
> doesn’t matter if the cursor hovers over “Appstore for Android”
> momentarily — the user is probably heading toward “Learn more about
> Cloud Drive.”

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would say it was a dropdown menu that is set to always be visible when the viewport is large enough to accommodate it. I don't think it's a web design pattern that is so often used, or special, that it really needs it's own name. I often refer to the little dropdown menus on most most modern responsive sites(while viewed on a phone or small screen), as mobile-menus. But that is just because they are the menu's state when on mobile...

Comment: I forgot to ask, what is the technology used in that 'Shop by department thingy'? Is it a CSS hover, or a Jquery plugin? And how does one know the difference?

Comment: This can most likely be created with just CSS. But a lot of people use jQuery in these scenarios. It becomes kinda a mess if you are trying to leave you menus visible for screen readers. If you "hide" the sub menus with jQuery .hide() or .fadeOut() methods - this sets the ul to display none. My suggestion is completely rethink your need for this type of menu. Building a site mobile first will really help you narrow down what is really important. It is very likely that there is a more intuitive way to navigate your site than this.